# Math Major Having Trouble

Tags: education, learning

I am a freshman at Alfred University. I've been out of school for 6 years and am returning as a non-traditional student.

I'm having some trouble that I hope someone may have insight for me. I love and adore mathematics and am endlessly intrigued and interested. Usually, back at home, I would work on little projects, like building toys or games or web apps and would explore the mathematics of the problems I was solving and generally have a wonderful time. Now that I'm in college I'm in a structured environment where we work in groups to solve problems in a workbook, and I'm assigned specific problem sets to work on in a specific topic every night.

I am having difficulty adjusting to this format of exploration and study.

I have a very free-wheeling approach to learning and it follows a spiritual bent; as I develop as an individual I also develop my skills and soak up more knowledge. The spirit isn't exactly something that you direct to sit down and do work and I'm not sure how to bridge the two worlds. No level of understanding that I've achieved will galvanize me to the discipline necessary to complete homework every day of the week, or even to set a goal of completing homework three times a week. Although now that I'm writing that, making a small goal like that seems much more reasonable.

I know I have to shed the habit of project-based learning however it's dying a hard death. I don't really know what to do about this.

Is this enough information for someone to possibly give me advice?

Thank you,

Khari

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. That sai, I'm voting to close this question  because there is no mathematical answer. But I am sympathetic. I think assigning boring problems from a workbook is not a good way to teach math to folks who have some imagination. Under the circumstances, probably all you can do is plug away at it a little bit at a time in hopes that passing this course serves your long term needs and goals.

Comment: Also there is a SE for academia.

Comment: Thank you for you sympathy! Understood. I may have to find another way to be creative and imaginative. I don't mind postponing this now to know I'll come back to it later more informed.

Comment: I'll repost this in the academia SE.